# Showing scaled percentages in a Highchart along with normal values

Tags: graph, highcharts, series

In google analytics, you can show clicks and Click Through Rate (a percentage) on the same chart.

This is essentially multiple series, one series contains absolute values vs date, and the other contains CTR (a percentage) vs date.

Highcharts scales it's Y axis correctly to the max and min of each series, but I can't figure out how to show the percentages on the same chart, scaled correctly.

One way I thought of is to scale the values of the percentage to the max of all the other values from other series on the chart, but this changes the actual value of the % so even though the graph looks nice, the data is straight up wrong.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you may need to create two series, one with real vlaues, one with calcuated percentages. Then bind series to different yAxis, and this should work fine.

Comment: "scaled correctly" may be a misleading phrase.  If you have to different measures that will be plotted on two different axes, there is really no such thing as "correct" scaling between the two - it is always arbitrary.

Comment: If I misunderstand what you are asking, this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837209/highcharts-percentage-of-total-for-simple-bar-chart/16838167#16838167