# Column chart tooltip with percentage

Tags: highcharts

I know that pie and bar chart has functionality to show tooltip with percentage, but I have column chart.
Is there any way to implement tooltip with percentage in column chart?

Comment: In the stacked column ? If not, you need to calculate this on your own in tooltip formatter.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, no there isn't stacked column. Could you please provide me with some examples with tooltip formatter?

Comment: you need to divide current point valye by sum all points from series.

Comment: See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837209/highcharts-percentage-of-total-for-simple-bar-chart/16838167#16838167

To apply this to the tooltip, simply copy the contents of the formatter function from the dataLabel object to the tooltip object.